# "Вася-биолог" или "Вася биолог"?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Правильно ли писать через дефис сочетание имени с профессией или родом деятельности человека?

Почему возник вопрос? У меня было написано в телефонных контактах через дефис (пример придумал произвольный), но при переносе контактов на другой телефон засомневался слегка, правильно так или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **Вася-биолог**.

У Лопатина есть правило: Составные имена, в которых вторая часть является... нарицательным именем в роли приложения, пишутся через дефис, напр.: Рокфеллер-старший, Дюма-сын; Илья-пророк, Николай-угодник (и Никола-угодник); Иван-царевич, Иванушка-дурачок.

У Розенталя эта тема изложена [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111).

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла! Значит, зря сомневался.)

Comment: Сибилла, в Википедии в статье "Буш, Джордж Уокер" встречаем: "Буш-младший", но в статье "Буш (фильм)": "Буш младший", "Буш старший". Это ошибка или все-таки возможны варианты?

Comment: Старший; после собственных имен пишется через дефис, напр.: Рокфеллер-старший, Рони-старший, но в нек-рых ист. прозвищах - раздельно, напр.: Катон Старший, Плиний Старший  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=старший&all=x

Answer (score 1):

1) Дефис ставится, если имя собственное стоит перед  нарицательным существительным: Волга-река.
При обратном порядке слов дефис не ставится: река Волга.

2) Дефис ставится между двумя нарицательным существительным: *бабушка-старушка, сосед-художник,* если первое из них нельзя заменить прилагательным. Например, *старушка бабушка* — дефис не нужен (можно сказать *старая бабушка*).

3) Имена, фамилии, прозвища людей не являются приложениями, в отличие от других имён собственных, и дефис не ставится. (В Вашем случае, я думаю, именно их будет много в телефонной книжке.)

4) Дефис не ставится, если первым элементом являются распространённые слова– обращения: гражданин, товарищ, господин, мистер, фрау, пан и т. д.

Поэтому *биолог Вася*  без дефиса, а *Вася-биолог* — через дефис.
P. S. По-моему, я правильно дефис напечатала: сначала как привыкла, а потом как положено — исправила во всех местах.

Comment: Спасибо! *По-моему, я правильно дефис напечатала...* Не совсем.) У Вас получилось короткое тире.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой не привередничайте. ))))  Во-первых размеры всех этих тире и дефисов регулируются типографскими правилами, а не правилами правописания. Во-вторых, замена даже длинного тире на дефис (и наоброт, хотя это реже) - вполне обычное дело дело в интернете. Разумеется, если верстка сама по себе не критична, т. е. когда речь не идет о дизайне серьезного издания.

Comment: *Во-вторых, замена даже длинного тире на дефис... - вполне обычное дело дело в интернете.* С этим согласен, а что наоборот — нет.)

Comment: Артём, я учту Ваши замечания. Но Вы слишком строги, я старалась. Behemothus, спасибо. Я Вас люблю.